# Emulate goto in Java

Tags: java

I have code (simplified hypothetical example):

```
public String handleEditRequest(...) {
    if (isBadArg()) {
       ...
       req.getSession().setAttribute("errorMessage", "...");
       return "redirect:/product/edit" + id + "/.htm";
    }
    if (isEntityNotInDataBase()) {
       ...
       req.getSession().setAttribute("errorMessage", "...");
       return "redirect:/error.htm";
    }
    ...
    return "redirect:/product/show" + id + "/.htm";
}
```

Now I have task to add SLA timing calculation to this code. If I have only one return statement I just wrap method body in:

```
public String handleEditRequest(...) {
    Timer timer = new Timer().start();
    // ... CODE ...
    slaService.send(timer.stop());
    return "redirect:/product/show" + id + "/.htm";
}
```

But error handling code block such solution. There are many possibilities. For example add:

```
timer.stop();
slaService.send(timer);
```

before any `return` statement. But this lead to code duplication.

Or use `try {} catch () {}` (inspired to me by Emacs Elisp experience):

```
private static class GotoError extends Throwable {}

public String handleEditRequest(...) {
    Timer timer = new Timer().start();
    String redirectUrl = "redirect:/product/show" + id + "/.htm";
    try {
        if (isBadArg()) {
           ...
           req.getSession().setAttribute("errorMessage", "...");
           redirectUrl = "redirect:/product/edit" + id + "/.htm";
           throw new GotoError();
        }
        if (isEntityNotInDataBase()) {
           ...
           req.getSession().setAttribute("errorMessage", "...");
           redirectUrl = "redirect:/error.htm";
           throw new GotoError();
        }
        ...
    } catch (GotoError e) { }
    slaService.send(timer.stop());
    return redirectUrl;
}
```

But today I rethink and use `do { ... break; ... } while (false);` paradigm (after googling I found `while (true) {if () {break} .... break;}` example, but I hate final break statement!!):

```
public String handleEditRequest(...) {
    Timer timer = new Timer().start();
    String redirectUrl = "redirect:/product/show" + id + "/.htm";
    do {
        if (isBadArg()) {
           ...
           req.getSession().setAttribute("errorMessage", "...");
           redirectUrl = "redirect:/product/edit" + id + "/.htm";
           break;
        }
        if (isEntityNotInDataBase()) {
           ...
           req.getSession().setAttribute("errorMessage", "...");
           redirectUrl = "redirect:/error.htm";
           break;
        }
        ...
    } while (false);
    slaService.send(timer.stop());
    return redirectUrl;
}
```

What construct to use for goto in error checking code in Java? Do I miss some build-in language constructs that naturally solve problem?

**PS**

C-like error handling come from my 10 year in plain C and allow to live with linear code. Many Java spaghetti look like:

```
if (!bad1()) {
    if (!bad2()) {
        if (!bad3()) {
            if (!bad4()) { ... }}}}
```

when this can be written like:

```
if (bad1())
   return errorCode;
if (bad2())
    throw new Ex();
if (bad3())
   return null;
if (bad4())
   break;
// Now do job, all fine!
```

Comment: Maybe something like `timer.start(); try {...code with multiple returns here...} finally {slaService.send(timer.stop());}`?

Comment: +1 for the absolutely shocking title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap the whole method in another one:

```
public String handleEditRequest(...) {
    Timer timer = new Timer().start();
    try {
        return handleEditRequestImpl(...);
    } finally {
        timer.stop();
        slaService.send(timer);
    }
}

private String handleEditRequestImpl(...) {
    // Lots of code
}
```

If `handleEditRequest` is implementing an interface, you could even potentially use a [proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) to automatically time *all* invocations of methods in that interface. (The proxy would implement the interface by handling each method the same way: start timer, invoke the real method, stop timer.)

(As noted elsewhere, it looks like you could quite possibly centralize more of your error handling too...)

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest this as well.  It looks to me like you're just trying to do to many things in one method.  Simplify.

Comment: Thanks for tip about proxy! I already use Spring framework and able to put filter in invocation chain.  +1

Answer (score 2):

The obvious thing to do is to put all your error code in a separate function and use `return` to break out. You can even relay a status or throw an exception.

I use `do{...}while(false);` in Java a fair bit but it is rather anachronistic.